# SQL Group by only correlative rows

Tags: sql, group-by, vertica

Say I have the following table:

```
Code A  B  C Date       ID
------------------------------
50   1  1  A 2018-01-08 150001  
50   1  1  A 2018-01-15 165454  
50   1  1  B 2018-02-01 184545  
50   1  1  A 2018-02-02 195487
```

I need the sql query to output the following:

```
Code A  B  C Min(Date)  Min(ID)
-------------------------------
50   1  1  A 2018-01-08 150001
50   1  1  B 2018-02-01 184545
50   1  1  A 2018-02-02 195487
```

If I use standard group by, rows 1,2,4 are grouped in 1 row, and this is not that I want. 
I want to select the row with MIN(date) and MIN(id) from the duplicate records that are together based on column code, A, B and C 
in this case 1st 2 rows are duplicates so i want the min() row.
and 3rd and 4th row are distinct.

Note that the database is Vertica 8.1, that is very similar to Oracle or PostgreSQL

Comment: Why the initial row count is 4 and the result is 3? What columns did you take to group by them?

Comment: My group by columns are: Code, A, B and C. If I execute standard group by query I get 2 rows, but I want 3 in the result.

Comment: yes that is the work of group by. but your output is not a result of group by from any angle.  why do you need  A's value twice?

Comment: In your results, line 1 and 3 should be grouped, no?   group by code,a,b,c only gives 2 lines with the data you've given us.

Comment: In my desired results, rows 1 and 2 are grouped because are secuencially by ID and Date, and row 4 is not grouped because there is a different row before. The finallity of the query is to delete rows that not give us rellevant information.

Comment: The real table is a aud log of changed records. Every change by users is a new record in the aud table, but we want a table where only are rows that have changes in the grouped columns.

Comment: Ok I understood but 
`50   1  1  A 2018-01-08 165454`  
`50   1  1  A 2018-01-15 150001`
`50   1  1  B 2018-02-01 184545`
what u want as o/p in this senario

Comment: No, I need 195487 because it is a real change from column value B to column value A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need the analytic function **LAG()**. Using this function, you can get the value of the previous row (or NULL if it's the first row itself). So you can check if the value on the previous row is different or not, and filter accordingly.

I'm not familiar with Vertica, but this should be the correct documentation for it: https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Analytic/LAGAnalytic.htm

Please try the query below, it should do it:

```
SELECT l.Code, l.A, l.B, l.C, l.Date, l.ID
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               LAG(t.C, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Code, t.A ORDER BY t.Date) prev_val
          FROM table_1 t) l
 WHERE l.C != l.prev_val
    OR l.prev_val IS NULL
 ORDER BY l.Code, l.A, l.Date
```

Comment: Yeah, it is just what I was finding for. It works! But my table have several columns to compare. Is there another way to make it more simple?

Comment: @AbelMartinez I guess this is more of a procedural problem rather than a pure SQL problem. You can solve this using SQL's analytic functions, but in Oracle for example it's probably easier to just solve it using PL/SQL. Does it get too much complicated adding more columns? I can't think of a different solution off the top of my head, and I don't have the actual example so I can't say. Maybe you could create a new question for that